# .click() is not working on the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

I an having a scenario in my site that user has the option to select one from the yes or no through radio buttons provided. In this I have a persistance logic that holds the ID for the input radio button and the value that has checked.

on reloading the page I have to put the radio button to checked which he has selected. 
I am using :

```
document.getElementById($scope.preservedData.userData[i].id).click();
```

where `UserData[i].id` holds the ID for the radio button.

```
<div class="radios col-xs-6">
    <input type='radio' id="yesforques${resultsList.index}" name='question${resultsList.index}' ng-click="macinitialquestions($event,value,${resultsList.index})">
    <label for="yesforques${resultsList.index}">
        <span class="tkh-icons RadioBG">&nbsp;</span>
        <b> Yes </b>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radios no col-xs-6">
    <input type='radio' id="noforques${resultsList.index}" name='question${resultsList.index}'  ng-click="macinitialquestionsRevert(${resultsList.index})">
    <label for="noforques${resultsList.index}">
        <span class="tkh-icons RadioBG">&nbsp;</span>
        <b> No </b>
    </label>
</div>
```

I have already tried the solutions provided like giving `cursor : pointer` to the input but no luck. My click is not highlighting the radio button can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById($scope.preservedData.userData[i].id).checked = true;
```

**JQuery:**

```
$($scope.preservedData.userData[i].id).prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: prepend `#` to `id` in jQuery statement